# Can we hide the Menu Option from Docusign header

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

We want to customize Docusign a bit these are the two images . That shows what we want to customize

[image]

We also want the consent Checkbox to come in the end of the signature flow

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Vikram, the first thing (hiding menu) can probably be done using some custom javascript if you embed the signing experience inside an iframe. This is not a supported feature, so you're on your own.
The second thing is not possible as it is a legal requirement to first require consent before new signers can use DocuSign (you only have to do this 1 time BTW).